# How to indent second line of an item enumerate

Tags: indentation, enumerate

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Solve the equation \\
    \hspace*{24cm} $x^2 = y$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I want it such that there's a blank space/indent so that the equation starts further right than the instructions. I've tried `\indent`, `\paragraph`, and `\hspace*` as you can see and none of it seems to work. I know I could get this to work by starting a new level of enumerate, but I was just wondering if there was another way, since I have to do this many times in the document.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want `\item Solve the equation \[x^2 = y.\]`? If you are, you can try `\\ \quad $x^2=y$.`

Comment: Indentation by `24 cm`? How wide is your papersize?

Comment: welcome to the site! :) have you tried using `\[x^2=y\]`?

Comment: I haven't tried \[x^2=y\] and it works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (although I would **not** use it personally this way)? Using `\hfill` to 'push' the equation to the right margin.

(I assume that the original `\hspace*{24cm}` was meant to shift the equation to the right margin)

However, this might look awkward for a bunch of several equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Solve the equation 

    \hfill $x^2 = y$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Solve the equation \\
              \makebox[\linewidth]{$x^2 = y$} % centred equation
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```