# Indent 2nd line of an item in description environment

Tags: spacing, description

I have some equations that span multiple lines. In the document, I have the following description environment:

```
\begin{description}
\item[(F1)]
$First Line \\$, 
$Second Line \\$
$Third Line $
\end{description}
```

The effect that I am trying to achieve, is to indent the second line and third line as follows, but it does not work:

```
\begin{description}
\item[(F1)]
$First Line \\$, 
\quad $Second Line \\$
\quad\quad $Third Line $
\end{description}
```

I have tried using \quad inside and outside the $$, but failed. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

P.S. The solutions suggested in [How to indent second line of an item enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294488/how-to-indent-second-line-of-an-item-enumerate) 
are not what I need. Also, I am not able to change any formatting commands. I need to do this simply by using something like \quad, \hspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\hspace*`, and  write `\\` outside mathmode:

```
\begin{description}
\item[(F1)]
$First Line $,\\
\hspace*{1em}$Second Line$ \\
\hspace*{2em}$Third Line $
\end{description}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why not define each line as a paragraph instead of breaking the line with `\\` ? This allows for `\quad` to work. Also you can use `\qquad` for double quad.

my suggestion:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[(F1)]
    $First Line $,

    \quad $Second Line$

    \qquad $Third Line $
\end{description}
```